# zend2 route urlencode specialchars

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, constraints, special-characters

I have a problem by writing a route constraint for strings with special chars.
when adding a string to url like this

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('routename', array('search_string'=>$search_string));
```

ZF2 automatically generates an url-encoded url like

```
http://test/search_stringr%C3%BCs
```

But now I get an 404 error. The route has following constraint:

```
'search_string'=> '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
```

How can I tell my route to read url-encoded parameters with %?

Comment: Please answer your own question and set the answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution to this myself. Using the following as a route constraint solved it:

```
'search_string' => '[a-zA-Z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*',
```